# How to hide my application from home screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have developed iOS application which support custom scheme.
I don't want end user launch my app from app button in home screen.
The app must be launched by link with custom scheme.
How can I hide my application from home screen.
Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not allow to do that on iOS because of security purposes. On iOS 14, users can move apps to the App Library, but it must done by the app user. On developer side you can't do this.